# throttle data transfer using dd over ssh connection

Tags: ssh, throttling, dd, oraclelinux

I am using dd to transfer data over two machines, command which used is ,

```
dd bs=1M if=/dev/loop0 status=progress | sshpass -p mypassword ssh root@192.168.111.11 dd bs=1M of=/dev/loop0 iflag=fullblock conv=sparse
```

Aim is to throttle the network usage while data transfer using [throttle](https://linux.die.net/man/1/throttle) command, But which is not present in server machine `Oracle Linux Server - Linux 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 x86_64`

How can I install throttle in server machine  ?

Is there any other mechanism to throttle data transfer through the above command ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done this using [trickle](https://linux.die.net/man/1/trickle)

```
dd bs=1M if=/dev/loop0 status=progress | trickle -s -d 1024 -u 1024 sshpass -p mypassword ssh root@192.168.111.11 dd bs=1M of=/dev/loop0 iflag=fullblock conv=sparse
```

> The above trickle command will limit the download bandwidth (-d) 1024
> KB/s and limit the upload bandwidth (-u) 1024 KB/s.